# Orthogonal projection of a line on a plane, parametric equations

Tags: geometry

First sorry if I don't write it correctly, but English is not my native language. So I have to find the parametric equations of the orthogonal projection of the line
$$l: \{ x-4y-z-3=0 |and| x-6y+z-13=0 $$
on the plane :
$$\alpha:x-y+3z-5=0$$
My text book says this answer is : $l':x=2+24t,y=9t,z=1-5t$. First of all how do I solve this? I thought of finding two points on $l$ and then using the normal vector of $\alpha$ (1;-1;3), see their coordinates on the plane and find the line that crosses them, namely $l'$. But I don't know how to convert that equation to parametric equations.Any help on the problem and it's solution are welcomed. Also can you point me to some problems with explanations concerning traversals, I tried looking online but couldn't find anything useful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the intersection of plane with the line (solve the system), say $A$. Take any other point on the line, say $B$. Find the parallel and orthogonal components of $AB$ in direction of $N$ where $N$ is the normal vector to the plane. The orthogonal component shows the direction of the projected line.

-- Maybe not optimal but should work.